# how do I transition conduit through a half-inch OSB shed wall?

Tags: electrical, conduit, shed

I'm running a 15 amp circuit to a small shed using underground 3/4" PVC conduit. I'm using an LB box to enter the side of the shed as shown in the picture below. The female end LB box protrudes about half an inch into the shed. The wall is only half inch OSB plus a very thin panel veneer.

I want to turn the conduit up and into a disconnect.  I was planning on using a junction box with the LB came through, but I suppose I could just use conduit to go all the way to the disconnect.

What would be the best way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What style of disconnect device are you using here? A pullout switch (A/C disconnect), a safety switch (with the handle on the side), a main breaker in a loadcenter (breaker panel), or a simple snap switch (light switch) since this is a single 15A circuit we're talking about here?

Comment: It's a pull out (AC) disconnect.  I'm not sure if it's even required, but I figured it would be good to have since the breaker is not conveniently located.  I was planning on mounting that a few feet above where the conduit comes through the wall.  I just need to make the transition through the wall and probably from pvc to metal.

Comment: Were you planning on finishing the inside of the shed?

Comment: No. I just want to mount the conduit/junction box/disconnect directly to the OSB... Shimming if necessary.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want this disconnect to be indoors, by the way?

Comment: I guess I see no reason for it to be outside and exposed to the elements.  It's probably very rarely, if ever going to be used. Plus I figured it would be a good place to convert from THWN to romex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completed the project and all is well.

1. I added some 2x4 blocking to provide a bit more depth to work with.
2. I solvent welded a small piece of 3/4" conduit between the female
   end of the LB coming through the wall sheathing and a threaded
   terminal adapter (the small piece of conduit is completely embedded
   in the fittings and not visible).
3. I then spun on a metal junction box on the terminal adapter until
   snug against the blocking
4. I ran 3/4" conduit from the junction box up to the disconnect.
5. The load side of the disconnect is 14/2 Romex.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

.

Comment: Good overall.  One thing though: does the ground wire make a pitstop at the metal box before continuing on to the disconnect?

Comment: It does not. Does it need to?

Comment: Yes, since its a metal box, it needs to be grounded.

Comment: Thanks.  I overlooked that.  I will ground the box.  Can I strip the insulation without cutting the wire and screw it to the box?

Comment: The "strip and screw" for an onwards ground is something I'm not sure about, myself